# how to test if condition and return statement inside jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I just started learning Jest.
what are other ways to test this function for If case and return statement using Jest ?
This is function to test with Jest

```
const extractInfo = (description: string) => {
        const info= description.match('descriptionInformation');
        if (info) {
          return info[0];
          }
         return 'hello jest';
        };
```

Tried below testcases to check
Info.test.ts

```
  test('extractInfo method to be defined', () => {
    expect(extractInfo ).toBeDefined();
  });

  test('extractInfo to be called when Info has blank string', () => {
    const BLANK_STRING = '';
    expect(extractInfo ).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(extractInfo ).toHaveBeenCalledWith(BLANK_STRING);
  })

    const extractInfo = (Info: string) => {
        const info= description.match(jestinformation);
        if (info) {
          return info[0];
          }
         return 'hello jest';
        };
```

Please provide ways to cover each lines. Thank you

Comment: `expect(extractInfo ).toHaveBeenCalled();` doesn't make any sense, you never call it and it's not a mock. It's really very unclear what your trying to do here. "test" isn't a valid goal

Comment: What's `description` and what is `jestinformation`? What's your expected output? Why are in adding a variable `Info` into your function then never using it? Literally none of this make any sense

Comment: @Liam, Updated question. Basically I have  javascript function extractInfo  for this function, I need to write testcase using Jest. expected output may be string matched it or not as per my understanding. If you are okay to explain me how to cover each lines using Jest using different testcases, please answer here, thankyou. I think it is clear now after updating question.

Comment: Your edits are not clarifying, your just saying the same things in a slightly different order. I'd suggest your read up on what unit testing is as you seem to be confused with the basic principles at play here. To test `extractInfo` you need to say if I input x I expect y out of this function. Your current "tests" are (To be brutally honest) just nonensense

Comment: yes, for that I Posted this question @Liam to check what's wrong with this. Please answer it in writing testcase using Jest and simply what you written input is X and output is Y you can write test case on same and I will check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets boil this down to:

> I want to test this function:
>
> ```
> const extractInfo = (Info: string) => {
>         const info= description.match(jestinformation);
>         if (info) {
>           return info[0];
>           }
>          return 'hello jest';
>         };
> ```

so to test this function you need to provide some input and expect an output. So you could write a test like this:

```
describe('extractInfo', () => {
   test('test 1', () => {
      //inputs
      const Info = '';
      const description = '';
      const jestinformation = '';

      //test
      const result = extractInfo(Info);
    
      //expect
      expect(result).toEqual('hello jest');
   });
});
```

So build your **input(s)**, run your **test**, assert/**expect** it's correct. This is your basic unit test pattern that applies to all unit tests in all languages/frameworks.

*that all said your input and outputs and what your testing are still all mangled but hopefully this answers [your basic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685338/how-to-test-regex-using-jest-and-without-exported-class/63685947#comment112617392_63685338)*